# update one column record in a csv with php

Tags: php

there are two columns  in my csv file,eg:

```
    image    gallery

    /1.jpg   /a.jpg;/b.jpg
   .....      .....
```

now i want to update the gallery content to  `/1.jpg;/a.jpg;/b.jpg`. namely,add the content of image collumn and  `;` to the gallery content.

the following is my code.when i run it. it can't update the content of the csv.i am get stucked.

```
$dir   = getcwd();
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $file) {
$parts = pathinfo($file);
if ($parts['extension']!="csv") {
    continue;
}
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[1]=$data[0].";".$data[1];
        fputcsv($file, $data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

open file in write or append mode and 
`fputcsv` expects first parameter to be resource and you have given file path
which is causing problem 
change it 
`fputcsv($handle, $data);`

Comment: i am sorry, i changed fputcsv($file, $data); as your said, but the  gallery collumn content doesn't have any change.

Comment: you are opening file in read mode and trying to update .how it will work ? it is not platform dependent windows or linux or unix

Comment: i am sorry, i am a new bie of php,could you tell me how to correct the code?

Comment: read this manual which might help you `http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php`

Comment: I would suggest create new csv file and write data into it

Comment: i am sorry, i still don't know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file permission first and after that you have to change the handle to both read and write and also please check whether the data[1] is having the values. 
Because in Your code the the data[0] only will fetch the lines as a string which is separated with ";" so you have to explode it and after that do the operations.